# gitlab.com SSH connection timed out

Tags: ssh, timeout, repository, gitlab

i try to get Gitlab with SSH working, but it won't.

I have done following steps:

1 ) generate ssh-key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@myhoster.com" -b 4096
```

2 ) named the key "id_rsa" in folder /Users/myUserName/.ssh/

3) copied the key via

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

4) insert the key into gitlab

When i now try to clone a repository i receive the following error:

```
$ git clone git@gitlab.com:myName/repositoryName/ repoName
Cloning into 'repoName'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Try use your own username `git clone myUsername@gitlab.com:myName/repositoryName/ repoName`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found myself with the same problem.

As **Adrian Dymorz** describe you can check if you have access to Gitlab through SSH with the following command:

```
ssh git@gitlab.com
```

You should receive a response like this:

```
...
Welcome to GitLab, <Gitlab ID Account>!
Shared connection to altssh.gitlab.com closed.
```

If not, then **betarrabara** should solve your issues **BUT** you should not provide your **id_rsa** but your **id_rsa.pub** instead:

```
Host gitlab.com
Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
User git
Port 443
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: it still throws 

```bash 

ue@DESKTOP-EVCRRVA /cygdrive/c/Users/ue/.ssh
$ ssh git@gitlab.com
The authenticity of host '[altssh.gitlab.com]:443 ([172.65.251.182]:443)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[altssh.gitlab.com]:443,[172.65.251.182]:443' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts
.
git@altssh.gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).


```

Answer (score 7):

GitLab.com runs a second SSH server that listens on the commonly used port 443, which is unlikely to be firewalled.

All you have to do is edit your `~/.ssh/config` and change the way you connect to GitLab.com.

```
Host gitlab.com
 Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
 User git
 Port 443
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Source: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/

Comment: You can learn about modfying your config file here https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/

Answer (score 5):

I tried the above method but remove the .pub in last line because it said not correct format. And it's worked.

```
Host gitlab.com
 Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
 User git
 Port 443
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

`ssh git@gitlab.com`

It should open a connection which gets closed immediately.

If you get a timeout, you may are behind a firewall which blocks the connection. In that case, you should add a rule which allows you to connect.

Comment: how can you please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

> In my case, my EC2 instance is restarted and the IP address got
> changed(due to restart), but I forget to update my server IP
> in ".gitlab-ci.yml" file. Once I have updated the correct IP, pipeline
> is successful.
>
> PS: I am practising a use case in "Techworld with Nana" course.